# Facing authencation issue in map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

**Request**: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=d&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCLZfb4gWRRKdrNec5Ep8ZNibJS5BmpNNA

**Response**

```
{
 "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to  use this API key. Request received from IP address 117.202.254.4, with empty referer",
 "predictions" : [],
 "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
 }
```

I have enabled following apis. But still facing issue(check response)
`Google Places API Web Service`
`Google Maps Android API`
`Google Maps Directions API`
`Google Maps Geolocation API`
`Google Places API for Android`

Answer (score 2):

This you Google map api key creation problem.

Your Create key for only android but this request you need to create key for Web browser.

or you can create key for all.

Thanks

Comment: so i want to  set keyrestrction: None?

Comment: how to create key web browser?

Comment: Better set "None"